# Approximate raster image based on Cubic Bezier

Tags: pixel, bezier, spline, cubic

I am unable to wrap my head around this problem.
I have a Cubic Bezier spline on screen, my goal is to have it built with "big pixels".

Here's the picture to show what I am talking about:
[image]

Comment: Your question's title says "approximate rasted image based on cubic Bezier" but your picture seems to suggest that you want to "approximate cubic Bezier based on rasterized image". Please clarify which way you want to do.

Comment: Okay, so, what have you tried to so far? The obvious place to start is to google for "rasterize bezier curve", and read a few of the many pages, then start writing your own code: scale down your curve so that "regular pixels" count as "big pixels", rasterize the curve the normal way, then scale the "pixels" back up. Done.